# Replace characters with word in PHP?

Tags: php, html, string, replace

Want to replace specific letters in a string to a full word.

I'm using:

```
    function spec2hex($instr) {

   for ($i=0; $i<strlen($instr); $i++) {  

        $char = substr($instr, $i,1);  

        if ($char == "a"){
            $char = "hello";
        }

        $convString .= "&#".ord($char).";"; 

    }

    return $convString;
}

$myString = "adam";

$convertedString = spec2hex($myString);

echo $convertedString;
```

but that's returning:

```
hdhm
```

How do I do this? By the way, this is to replace punctuation with hex characters.

Thanks all.

Comment: Your question is very vague - just give an example of input and desired output.

Comment: The issue you're running into is that `ord($char)` isn't always a single character, which is what `ord` expects.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/substr_replace

```
substr_replace($instr, $word, $i,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the occurrence of `a` with `hello` within the string you pass to the function, why not use PHP's [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
function spec2hex($instr) {    
  return str_replace("a","hello",$instr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ord()` expects only a SINGLE character. You're passing in `hello`, so ord is doing its thing only on the `h`:

```
php > echo ord('hello');
104
php > echo ord('h');
104
```

So in effect your output is actually

```
&#104;d&#104;m
```

Comment: No, but you can 'explode' a string into individual characters and applies ord in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

it you want to use your same code just change `$convString .= "&#".ord($char).";";`

to `$convString .= $char;`

Answer (score 0):

I must assume that you don't want to have hex characters instead of punctuation but html entities. Be aware that str_replace(), when called with arrays, will run over the string for multiple times, thus replacing the ";" in "`&#123;`" also!

Your posted code is not useful for replacing punctuation.

use strtr() with arrays, it doesn't have the drawback of str_replace().

```
$aReplacements = array(',' => '&#44;', '.' => '&#46;'); //todo: complete the array
$sText = strtr($sText, $aReplacements);
```